# How do I disable anchor tag and change html() during an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<a class="mr-2 mb-2 btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" onclick="edit_init(this)" href="#4CE10703YB"><i class="ti-info"></i></a>
```

jQuery:

```
 function edit_init(anchor){
       $("#edModal").html("");
       ref = anchor.href.substr(anchor.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
       ref = ref.replace(/^#/, "");

        $.post("modal.php",{ajax_get_edModal:1,ajax_modal_for:ref},function(data){

            $("#edModal").html(data);
        });


    }
```

So everything is working fine, but now I want to change the `html()` inside that anchor tag to something like "loading.." and disable it during the duration of the ajax request.

Comment: So change the html like you do for the modal.... and set the disabled property.

Comment: when i do so, the ajax code wont work

Comment: What did you try, I am guessing you had a syntax error that shows up in your console.

Comment: here is the log error:  Uncaught TypeError: anchor.html is not a function
    at edit_init

Comment: Well that means you treated a DOM reference like it was jQuery. `$(anchor).html("loading...").prop("disabled", true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply below changes to your function, in order to achieve your task.

```
function edit_init(anchor){
    $prevHtml = $(anchor).html();
    $href = $(anchor).attr('href');
    $(anchor).removeAttr('href');
    $(anchor).html('Loading....');
    $(anchor).attr('disabled',true);
           $("#edModal").html("");
           ref = anchor.href.substr(anchor.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
           ref = ref.replace(/^#/, "");

            $.post("modal.php",{ajax_get_edModal:1,ajax_modal_for:ref},function(data){

                $("#edModal").html(data);
                $(anchor).html($prevHtml);
                 $(anchor).removeAttr('disabled');
                 $(anchor).attr('href',$href);
            });
        }
```

Comment: My pleasure @kingraphaII :)

Comment: I don't believe the `disabled` attribute is valid on `a` elements.  You would have to call `preventDefault()` on the event to essentially disable the link.

Comment: oh thanks just realized that, so took advantage of bootstrap's disabled class

Comment: I agree with @TomPietrosanti, so another way is to remove the **href** attribute of anchor tag when function is called and then again setting it back to the same **href**

Answer (score 0):

Use `beforeSend` to do something while ajax request, for example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'example.php',
    data: form.serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('.yourTag').html('loading...');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('.yourTag').html(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        $('.yourTag').html('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like it can work, but.... its not a form actually, those will be just static values, so idk about that serialize part

Comment: Is it just an example, the important is beforeSend, and forget $post syntax wich is actually deprecated, use $ajax syntax